# What is the default value for PATH in Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows-8

I have accidentally overwritten the `PATH` variable in my freshly installed Windows 8 Pro. I have used some answers mentioned in some other questions in Stack Overflow, but still the `help` command is not working in my command prompt.

Can someone give me the `PATH` values for a new system?

Comment: @mic84, you're still adding the "two-space Return" line breaks to other people posts. Why? Please STOP doing that! (Paragraphs are split up using an EMPTY line in between two paragraphs. But paragraphs surely can have multiple sentences in them. The `<br>` line breaks you are adding are rarely appropriate.) Also, don't add "thankyou" to posts. First of all, it would be two words. Secondly, it's just adding noise.

Comment: @Arjan Sadly he has enough reputation to edit without approval, one of the reasons, I don't edit a question unless it has to be done.

Comment: Yeah, @Ramhound, I'm sure it's done with good intentions, but [my earlier comments did not help either](http://superuser.com/questions/952324/do-i-need-ssd-disks-to-work-with-full-format-gopro-4-raw-movies/952597#comment1303692_952597).

Comment: But then, @Ramhound, SE [does not seem to want to add "paragraphs" to the editing help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135252/add-paragraphs-to-markdown-help)...

Comment: @Arjan Is it possible to view all edits by a particular user? Viewing mic86's edits would be quite amusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of internet searching does the trick. From [official MS forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/22a2ae01-1c2c-439c-bc13-76c9e0d7a255/windows-8-default-path-variables?forum=w8itprogeneral)

> this is the default PATH for system:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```